# 1000 genomes missing SNPs on chr X in GRCh38

Tags: snp, impute2, 1000genomes

I am trying to get a reference together for imputation using the 1000 genomes data set. The GRCh38 version of the data set was made available earlier this year, but seems to be missing a significant number of SNPs on the X chromosome (~96%).

Is there any resource that can explain why? I have tried searching on their home page with no luck.

The data sets in question are [GRCh38](http://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000_genomes_project/release/20190312_biallelic_SNV_and_INDEL/), [GRCh37](http://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/).

Comment: Please do not cross post to BioStars, Stack Exchange and 1000 Genomes helpdesk as it can create duplicate work:
https://www.biostars.org/p/399254/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told you on 1000 genomes helpdesk:
Because of the ploidy settings we used for our variant calling, we only called variants in the the pseudoautosomal region on the X chromosome. We are working on settings to correctly analyse X variants in both males and females and plan to analyse X properly soon.

Answer (score 2):

I think these are [biallelic snps](http://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000_genomes_project/release/20190312_biallelic_SNV_and_INDEL/20190312_biallelic_SNV_and_INDEL_README.txt):

> The set is restricted to biallelic SNVs and INDELs.

If you check the [liftover version](http://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/supporting/GRCh38_positions/), the chromosome X is complete...